# What does it mean `T : 'static`?

Tags: rust

What is the proper understanding of the restriction `T : 'static` ?
As I understand it means "anything implementing T should not have a reference / pointer either directly or indirectly". I am asking because I used to think that it means anything implementing T should exist during the whole lifetime of the application, but such interpretation looks wrong for me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new understanding is correct. `T: 'static` means `T` does not contain lifetimes, or *may* live during the entire program, but doesn't have to.

See also [Common Lifetime Misconceptions: if `T: 'static` then `T` must be valid for the entire program](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program).

For example, [`String: 'static` holds](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f91da47b28602be15b1c24dcab12ebb), but you can drop a `String` whenever you want and you cannot access it anymore. It is just that if I have a `String` and I *don't* drop it, I can hold it forever without have to worry it will be invalidated behind my back because, say, the underlying storage was freed.

Comment: @Kos It's not mine, but yeah, it's a very recommended read :)